# Why binwalk reports wrong results?

Tags: binwalk

I have a mp4 file (20M size) then I run:

```
$ binwalk myfile.mp4
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8061349       0x7B01A5        gzip compressed data, ASCII, last modified: 2038-02-02 16:33:05 (bogus date)
```

although the date seems weird, using `dd`:

```
$ dd if=myfile.mp4 bs=1 skip=8061349 of=zipfile.gz
12755682+0 records in
12755682+0 records out
12755682 bytes (13 MB, 12 MiB) copied, 50.5952 s, 252 kB/s
```

now with `gzip`:

```
$ gzip -l zipfile.gz 
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
           12755682           825241902  98.5% zipfile


$ gzip -d zipfile.gz 
gzip: zipfile.gz: invalid compressed data--format violated
```

So how can I be sure the `binwalk` output is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I've never seen binwalk used on a mp4 or any other media file.
As this software is developed for extracting firmware, I am not sure if this would even work.

You might want to read [binwalks FAQ](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)

From the FAQ:

> #### Why does binwalk's signature scan report false positive results?
>
> Binwalk does a pretty good job of analyzing potential file signatures
> and filtering out obvious false positives, but it is not perfect.
>
> Some signatures are more difficult to validate than others, and
> binwalk will always err on the side of caution; that is, it would
> rather report a potential false positive so that you can then
> independently validate or invalidate it, rather than not report a
> questionably valid result.

[This part of the FAQ](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#binwalk-found-an-xyz-file-but-the-xyz-utility-cant-process-it) might be of special interest for you.

You can have a look into binwalks [magic files](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/blob/master/src/binwalk/magic/compressed) and compare it to your data to get a clue why it got flagged as GZIP.

Comment: Tysm for the answer, looking at magic files section and a `hexdump` of my file there was a sequence of \x1f\x8b\x08 which due to the so low probability, was confusing!